# Are all mouse draggable objects in HTML5 canvas based on setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, setinterval

I am making a geometrical optics demo in HTML5 canvas, the mouse points the light source, you can craft some barriers, javascript do the calculation work and display light and shadow on on a line behind those barriers.

from those canvas drag'n'drop tutorials I found online, *all* of them are using `setInterval()` to make mouse interactions happen, which means the whole canvas is updated and re-painted all the time. This makes me feel the whole canvas business is an ugly hack.

My question is: are there any other way to make mouse interactions in `canvas` without the `setInterval()` way? I want to paint the background once and only redraw the moving part while `onmousemove` when the mouse is actually moving.

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I also use `setInterval()` for a canvas drawing application with mouse interaction. There is a function called `requestAnimationFrame` but it basically an enhanced version of `setInterval`, so perhaps not what you're looking for.

Comment: The problem is that a `<canvas>` is really like a canvas - you can't "un-draw" on it.

Comment: @Pointy: you could use two `<canvas>`, one for the background, and clear the other one for the mouse things each time.

Comment: @pimvdb like a double buffer?

Comment: @est: Well, I have a fullscreen background canvas which is painted once at startup, and another (smaller) one which does the drawing so many times a second. It would be silly to paint on a fullscreen canvas that many times a second.

Comment: @pimvdb Well yes that's true - you can also animate plain `<img>` elements over a canvas.

Comment: Another possibility would be to look at incorporating SVG, which is, IMHO, easier to program from a user event perspective.  Each element fires events in a similar way to HTML DOM events.  You could make all the interactive parts (and the background, even) SVG, but keep the light in a canvas layer on top (I'm not sure how you'd present that in SVG).  Just a thought.

Comment: I'm missing something or is this the perfect job for canvas.save() and canvas.restore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to finish this question, the answer should be `requestAnimationFrame` from `pimvdb`

Answer (score 1):

You can redraw the canvas **without** the element being dragged, then draw the element to a new canas on top of the base. Then you can use **absolute positioning** to move the one being dragged *without any redrawing*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mousemove available on the canvas element. I use it all the time and i believe it is very useful in your situation.

You could also do it with setInterva but that's sounds kind of dirty to me in this case. You need to get the mouse X and Y anyway, what beter place to do that in the mousemove event!

Answer (score 1):

Look at that article: http://www.splashnology.com/article/fifteen-puzzle-in-libcanvas/1632/

There are some ways to optimize canvas drawing. First of all - not redraw full canvas, only changed parts. And redraw only if something changed.

At work I create game based on [LibCanvas](http://libcanvas.github.com/) now and background I draw at another layer. Something like that:

```
var libcanvas  = new LibCanvas( 'canvas' ).start();
var background = libcanvas.createLayer( 'bg', 0 );
drawBackgroundAt  ( background );
startApplicationAt( libcanvas );
```

Answer (score 1):

First draw the background, then save the canvas with canvas.save().

On mouse interaction: canvas.restore() and draw your drawings.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are experiencing is that you need `setInterval` to update the canvas everytime you do mouseinteraction. And that feels a bit ugly to you because that's seems to you like "Hacking".

You don't have to feel bad about it, because you will need that mechanism for anything that should be animated.

But you can do "clipping" in the method you call through setInterval you could decide which part of your canvas should be updated and only redraw that part.

If you don't need constantly updating your content, because its not animated i agree to Elmer.

But updating the canvas through setInterval is neither ugly nor dirty ;-) It's the way you keep canvas updated if you want to animate something.